# Helping Determining Validity of Statement

Tags: calculus

If $\text{sup}$ $A$ $<$ $\text{inf}$ $B$ for sets $A\subset \mathbb R$ and $B\subset \mathbb R$, then there exists a $c\in \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $a<c<b$ for all $a\in A$ and $b\in B$.

I **think** the statement is true. When I picture the information on a number line it makes sense but if the statement is true I have to give a mini proof.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: yes i did, it is fixed.

Comment: Choose a $c$ such that $\sup A \lt c \lt \inf B\,$, then see why the inequalities would hold.

Comment: having trouble forming that proof @dxiv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**

Take $$c=\frac {\sup A+\inf B}{2} $$

then

$$a\le \sup A<c <\inf B\le b $$
if $a\in A $ and $b\in B $.

Comment: my question was edited...there was a typo i did not see